# BOUNCE animation does not work on the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, marker

As the title suggests, the BOUNCE animation doesn't work on the map, but I'm sure it has to work this way. Can you help me figure out where I'm wrong? This is the piece of code I use to add markers to the map

```
this.addMarker = function(lat, lng, url, title, icon, shadow, body, full_address, animation) {
        if(lat == 0.0) return;

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); 
    var zIndex = 99999 + this.numMarkers;

    var markerOptions = {
        position: latLng, 
        map: this.map,
        linkURL: '',
        zIndex: zIndex,
       // animation: "",//google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        title: title,
        full_address: full_address
    };
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerOptions, "mouseover", up)

    function up(){
        if(typeof animation == "undefined"){
            markerOptions.animation = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
        } else {
            markerOptions.animation = null;
        }
    }
    if(typeof icon !== "undefined" && icon.length > 0) markerOptions.icon = icon;
        else if(this.icon) markerOptions.icon = this.icon;

    // console.log(markerOptions); 

    if(typeof shadow !== "undefined" && shadow.length > 0) markerOptions.shadow = shadow; 
        else if(this.shadow.length > 0) markerOptions.shadow = this.shadow; 

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions); 

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<div class="gmaps-box" style="width: 100%;"><h5>'+title+'</h5><p>'+body+'</p></div>'
    }); 

    if(url.length > 0) marker.linkURL = url;
    if(this.hoverBox) marker.hoverBoxTitle = title; 
        else marker.setTitle(title); 

    this.markers[this.numMarkers] = marker;
    this.numMarkers++;

    if(marker.linkURL.length > 0) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
            // window.location.href = marker.linkURL; 
            infowindow.open(this.map, marker);

        }); 
    }
    if(markerOptions.icon !== "undefined" && this.iconHover) {
        var iconHover = this.iconHover; 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(e) {
            marker.setIcon(iconHover); 
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(e) {
            marker.setIcon(markerOptions.icon); 
        }); 
    }

    if(this.hoverBox) {

        var $hoverBox = this.hoverBox; 
        var offsetTop = this.hoverBoxOffsetTop;
        var offsetLeft = this.hoverBoxOffsetLeft; 

        var mouseMove = function(e) {
            $hoverBox.css({
                'top': e.pageY + offsetTop,
                'left': e.pageX + offsetLeft
            });
        }; 

        // console.log($hoverBox); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(e) {
            this._currentURL = url;
            $hoverBox.html("<span>" + marker.hoverBoxTitle + "</span>")
                .css('top', '0px')
                .css('left', '0px')
                .css('display', 'block')
                .css('width', 'auto')
                .css('z-index', 9999); 
            $hoverBox.show();

            $(document).mousemove(mouseMove); 
        }); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(e) {
            $hoverBox.hide();
            $(document).unbind("mousemove", mouseMove);
        }); 

    }
}
```

The result should look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: fiddle gives 404

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple and not worrying about scope, instead of calling `up` in `addEventListener`, you can try calling the function itself:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerOptions, "mouseover", function(){
        if(typeof animation == "undefined"){
            markerOptions.animation = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
        } else {
            markerOptions.animation = null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work that way either. I also tried to do so but it doesn't work, I don't understand the reason at all